# Проблема в позиционировании <div>

Tags: html

Каким образом можно расположить  по центру страницы, не используя margin?

Comment: Можно с flexbox

Answer (score 3):

Можно так

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color:tomato;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: background;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

А вообще способов много

Answer (score 0):

Для элементов с абсолютным позиционированием

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #248cec;
}

.elem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #9ed535;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```